# Package manager (pacman) not showing linux-headers for current kernel version

Tags: kernel, manjaro, pacman

I'm using Manjaro 20.0.1 with 5.6.11-1 kernel.

`uname -a`:

```
5.6.11-1-MANJARO
```

I've updated the pacman database with `sudo pacman -Syy`.

But if I try to install the linux headers, the latest ones correspond to 5.5:

```
sudo pacman -S linux-headers

:: There are 11 providers available for linux-headers:
:: Repository core
   1) linux316-headers  2) linux414-headers  3) linux419-headers  4) linux44-headers
   5) linux49-headers  6) linux53-headers  7) linux54-headers  8) linux55-headers
:: Repository community
   9) linux419-rt-headers  10) linux52-rt-headers  11) linux54-rt-headers
```

Am I missing some step?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by generating a mirror list with

```
sudo pacman-mirrors -f
```

After updating, the `linux56-headers` are present (also for 5.7).